# When I run the .bat file directly, it does not work

Tags: batch-file

My bat file creates firewall inbound rules.

Source like this:

```
echo off
set RULE_NAME="NTL CERVICARE"

:: Check user's computer bit
reg Query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" | find /i "x86" > NUL && set OS=32BIT || set OS=64BIT

:: .Exe file path
if %OS%==64BIT (
    set exePath="C:\program files (x86)\ntl\ntl cervicare\ntl cervicare.exe" 
) else (
    set exePath="C:\program files\ntl\ntl cervicare\ntl cervicare.exe"
)

:: If rule is not exist, make it.
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=%RULE_NAME% >nul
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo Inbound rules of %RULE_NAME% already exist. 
) else (
    :: Make inbound rule
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=%RULE_NAME% dir=in action=allow program=%exePath% enable=yes profile=private protocol=tcp localport=any remoteport=any
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=%RULE_NAME% dir=in action=allow program=%exePath% enable=yes profile=private protocol=udp localport=any remoteport=any
)
```

When I run this file via admin cmd it works without any problem.

**The problem is that if the bat file is run as an administrator through the icon, it is terminated without any action, and no firewall inbound rules are created.**

What's the problem?

---

**EDIT**

When I checked it on other people's computers, it worked fine. It doesn't work only on my PC, but it's difficult to determine what the problem is.

I checked both Windows 10 Home and 10 Pro. Mine is 10 Pro.

---

Comment: What is defined for property __Target__ of the shortcut file used by you to run the batch file with a double on an icon? BTW: Your detection of 32-bit or 64-bit Windows operating system is not good coded as the architecture of the processor does not matter. It is possible to run 32-bit Windows on a PC with a 64-bit processor.

Comment: @Mofi
**Target** is my .bat file that is my question's source. The reason is to let the user run as administrator. And I don't understand about OS Bit.
The path where the .exe file is installed varies depending on the user's computer, so it is intended to be mapped to it.

Comment: Add a `pause` at the end to be able to read potential error messages. Avoid `::`-style comments, particularly in a parenthesised block as they may cause unexpected behaviour…

Comment: The architecture of the processor has nothing to do with storage location of `ntl cervicare.exe`. All you really need is: `if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\ntl\ntl cervicare\ntl cervicare.exe" (set "exepath="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\ntl\ntl cervicare\ntl cervicare.exe"") else if exist "%ProgramFiles%\ntl\ntl cervicare\ntl cervicare.exe" (set "exepath="%ProgramFiles%\ntl\ntl cervicare\ntl cervicare.exe"") else (echo ERROR: Could not find "ntl cervicare.exe".&exit /B 1)`.

Comment: `:: Make inbound rule` is bad in your code. `::` is an invalid label. Labels inside a command block starting with `(` and ending with `)` result in __undefined behavior__. Use `rem` which is the command for comments (remarks). You should be able to find out why the batch file execution fails on right clicking on shortcut and executing it with __Run as administrator__ by appending `pause` at end of the batch file. I don't see any other syntax error. Hint: Read the Microsoft documentation about [application registration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/app-registration).